# Tomcat logging in eclipse ganymede

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging

I am using eclipse ganymede and tomcat 6.
Nothing appears in my console when im using tomcat 6

Any ideas of what I could do so that i can see logging on the console

All help greatly appreciated

Damien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat uses a logging framework. Look in the logs folder for the output. Add a console appender to the log4j.properties file.

Comment: would that be the logs directory of tomcat or an eclipse log directory?

Comment: Of Tomcat.  It actually has several layers of logging. Catalina is the internal logging.